# Canceling SLURM jobs without receiving email notifications

Tags: notifications, slurm

Given some SLURM jobs which were started using `sbatch --mail-type=ALL`, is there any way to cancel them without receiving the email notifications informing you that they were canceled? I was thinking of something like either using `scontrol` to change the jobs’ mail settings or some kind of flag for `scancel`, but couldn’t find anything helpful in the SLURM manuals.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This works only from SLURM version 20.02+

First, update the job, then cancel:

```
scontrol update jobid=<...> mailtype=NONE
scancel <...>
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for me:
`Update of this parameter is not supported: mailtype=NONE`
`Request aborted`
Is this something that can be configured by the administrator?

Comment: The feature is present on SLURM 20.02. If your system's version is older than that, AFAIK there is no clean way to interact with the mail settings once submitted.

Comment: I see, that’s too bad. If you add this to your answer, I can accept it.